# What troops should I train in a level 7 barracks?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I keep losing when I attack and I don't know what to train?

Comment: its all about the strategy behind the attack. If you are in lower levels just a swarm of troops works but in higher levels you need a plan. Might I suggest taking out the defenses with giants first? Use the giant and healer combo if possible.

Comment: depends on your goal and strategy. Can you elaborate on whether you are after resources or stars? Also what is the size of your army camps?

Comment: I want stars. The size is 135 troops

Comment: ...so you want trophies you mean? or stars for wars? either way its the same i guess... all you can really do is build up your army and then pick a target based upon your army. At first when i needed trophies and at a low cost...I did what I called 120 barbarian rush...exactly what it sounds like lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had trouble when I reached barracks level 7. For me wizards have always been a little better on defense then on offense.

My personal preference at this level is to create an army of around 10-12 giants, 4-6 wall-breakers, and split the rest of your supply between archers and goblins. Send in giants first to absorb the initial damage then send in wall-breaks to break the walls just as the giants are reaching them and follow up by attacking with the rest of your forces. If there are any defenses on the outside have the archers hit those, don't have your whole army attacking the same defensive structure at the same time.

You can try mixing in a few wizards (they are good), but for me they are time consuming to produce and expensive.

Final note is that at level 8 barracks the healer becomes a great asset to your army. Get 2 of those to back up your giants and you'll find yourself winning a lot more attacks!